# Checking a PIN number is correct according to it's card number

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently working on an assignment for college that I'm really stuck on.  I have to create an application to simulate an ATM machine using Visual Basic 2010.  I'm currently stuck trying to check whether the PIN number entered in the text box is correct for the card number selected in the combo box.  If the user enters the PIN incorrectly three times, the card is confiscated.  I am getting an error message at the moment saying "Object variable or With block variable not set".  Below is the code I have written:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class PinEntry

Public connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\ben\Documents\Programming\Year 2\Visual Studio\Assignment2\BankOfGlamorgan\EDP2011-BoG.mdb"
Friend connectionBG As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim commandCardNumber As New OleDbCommand()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim pinErrorCount As Integer
Dim ATMCardsBindingSource As New BindingSource
Dim SqlCommandCheckPIN As New OleDbCommand
Dim SqlCommandConfiscate As New OleDbCommand

Private Sub PinEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connectionBG.ConnectionString = connectionString
    commandCardNumber.Connection = connectionBG
    commandCardNumber.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandCardNumber.CommandText = "SELECT cardNumber FROM ATMCards"

    Try
        connectionBG.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = commandCardNumber
        da.Fill(ds, "ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DataSource = ds.Tables("ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DisplayMember = "cardNumber"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionBG.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnterPin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPin.Click
    Try
        Me.connectionBG.Open()
        Dim PIN As String
        Dim cardNo As String

        PIN = Me.txtPIN.Text
        cardNo = Me.ATMCardsBindingSource.Current("cardNumber")

        Me.SqlCommandCheckPIN.Parameters("@PIN").Value = PIN
        Me.SqlCommandCheckPIN.Parameters("@cardNumber").Value = cardNo
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = Me.SqlCommandCheckPIN.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows And pinErrorCount <= 2 Then
            My.Forms.Menu.ShowDialog()
            dr.Close()
            pinErrorCount = 0
            txtPIN.Text = ""

        ElseIf pinErrorCount = 2 Then
            dr.Close()

            MessageBox.Show("PIN Entered Incorrectly Three Times Card Now Confiscated", "Card Taken", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            cardNo = Me.ATMCardsBindingSource.Current("cardNumber")
            Me.SqlCommandConfiscate.Parameters("@cardNumber").Value = cardNo
            Me.SqlCommandConfiscate.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Else
            pinErrorCount = pinErrorCount + 1
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect PIN Please Try Again.", "Incorrect PIN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtPIN.Text = ""

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Me.connectionBG.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Updated code below:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class PinEntry

Public connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\ben\Documents\Programming\Year 2\Visual Studio\Assignment2\BankOfGlamorgan\EDP2011-BoG.mdb"
Friend connectionBG As New OleDbConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim commandCardNumber, commandPinNumber As New OleDbCommand()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim pinErrorCount, cardNumber, PIN As Integer
Dim oForm As Menu
Dim userInput As String

Private Sub PinEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connectionBG.ConnectionString = connectionString
    commandCardNumber.Connection = connectionBG
    commandCardNumber.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandCardNumber.CommandText = "SELECT cardNumber FROM ATMCards"
    commandPinNumber.Connection = connectionBG
    commandPinNumber.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandPinNumber.CommandText = "SELECT PIN FROM ATMCards WHERE cardNumber = ?"

    Try
        connectionBG.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = commandCardNumber
        da.Fill(ds, "ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DataSource = ds.Tables("ATMCards")
        cmbCardNumber.DisplayMember = "cardNumber"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionBG.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnterPin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPin.Click
    cardNumber = Convert.ToInt16(cmbCardNumber.Text)
    commandPinNumber.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter())
    commandPinNumber.Parameters(0).Value = cardNumber

    Try
        connectionBG.Open()
        dr = commandPinNumber.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            PIN = dr.Item("PIN").ToString
        End While
        dr.Close()
        If PIN = userInput Then
            MsgBox("Correct PIN")
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect PIN")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionBG.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub txtPIN_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPIN.TextChanged
    userInput = txtPIN.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: WHERE does the error happen - it basically means what is says - something you are using is not instanced.  you might have to remark out the Try/Catch to determine the line

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @KenWhite the error appears when I click the EnterPin button

Comment: "when I click the EnterPin button" is not a "line of code". Either comment out the `try..catch`, or set a breakpoint on the first line inside the `try` and run with debugging to identify the specific line that is causing the exception to be raised.

Comment: may have to do with the OleDbCommand `SqlCommandCheckPIN`- i cant see where the connection or SQL are set. maybe thats the next error

Comment: @KenWhite there are no errors in the debug panel, it is a message box that appears when I click the button.  Forgive me as I am a complete novice

Comment: thats is **your** messagebox from the catch block.  get rid of the Try/Catch so you can identify the line it is crashing on; or step thru the code line by line as Ken suggested

Comment: You've been asked twice to narrow the problem down, and I've given you specific instructions on how to do so. Please read my last comment again, and follow those instructions. We can't debug your code for you, because we don't have your data or the rest of your code. If you isolate the problem, we can probably help, but you need to do a little work first to make that possible.

Comment: how use the debugger in 600 chars or less: use F9 to set a breakpoint, then when it stops there, use F8 to execute (step) line by line (at this point, you can use the mouse to examine variables).  When it jumps to the catch - thats the line it is crashing on - usually easier to remove the try/catch and let it crash.   But you will want to learn the debug tools - more time is spent with them than the code editor (for us mortals anyway).

Comment: OK I've commented out the catch and when I ran it the following error message was shown: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is open.  The line in question is the conne

Comment: Which line is causing the error? - you dont seem to be setting the connection or connectionstring in that procedure.  (I do hope you commented out the Try AND the Catch).

Comment: OK disregard that last comment I had made changes to the original code that i had forgotten to delete.  Back to the original code now and I have this message on the line cardNo = Me.ATMCardsBindingSource.Current("cardNumber") An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Where does the program get the cardnumber from?  They apparently type in the PIN, but how do you get card number?  not from a SQL lookup, I hope.  (whats the analogy for swiping the card here)

Comment: It is taken from an access database.  I have used a data adapter to fill the combo box with the card numbers present in the 'cardNumber' field from the 'ATMCards' table in that database

Comment: The user chooses a card number from the drop down menu

Comment: ok, then for now anyway you dont need to BindingSource.  Comment it out.  Get the card number from the ComboBox.  the next error you will get is `Connection property has not been initialized.`; the one after that will be a SQL/Command Text error.

Comment: OK next error message after commenting out the binding source An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An OleDbParameter with ParameterName '@PIN' is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection.

Comment: For line  Me.SqlCommandCheckPIN.Parameters("@PIN").Value = PIN

Comment: there are multiple issues with the next 3 lines, see answer.  you do not have any SQL there containing "@PIN" is the gist

Comment: when you get it working, you should click the checkmark to mark this as answered; good luck

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I like that you pick a card number from a list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OleDBCOmmand` objects are typically used in a more disposable way than as module level variables.  In order to work, they also need a SQL string and a Connection object associated with them.  Ex:

```
   Dim sql As String = "SELECT etc etc etc WHERE something = ?"

   Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, dbCon)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", myVar)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", myVar)

        Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If rdr.HasRows Then
           ' do something interesting
        End If
    End Using
```

Here, both the SQL and DB Connection are associated with the Command Object when it is created.  The `Using` block assures it is properly disposed of when we are done with it.

Also, OleDbCommand objects do not support named parameters. Usually, it just ignores them.  The right way for Paramters is shown (ie `AddWithValue`) where you replace each `?` placeholder in the SQL string **in order** with the actual value.  **Do** be sure the data type matches.  If PIN is a number, you must add a number, not Text.

For the SQL, you are testing the PIN entered against a card number, so those are the param values.  Depending on how you construct the SQL you can either see if the PIN in the DB matches the one they gave OR just see if you get any rows back.

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work but to no avail...this is my updated code, any ideas?

Comment: closer, but there are still many problems.  examine my code and the comments: you are not associating a Connection or OleDbCommand Text with your OleDBCommand objects before you use them; I cant see where the Connection is ever opened.  Since we **did** solve the NullReferenceException, I think this answer should be accepted (click the check) and new one(s) posted for the new problems (think small - SO likes concrete probs vs fix my code ones).